# Optimal methods for mapping out molecules, atoms and nuclei and their energy levels?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, nuclear-physics, atomic-physics

I'm wondering if it would be possible to map out all the different types of molecules, atoms and nuclei and their energy levels on one page (even if in a generalised way)? But perhaps I'm referring to the periodic table here? Do representations differ according to whether one is looking at things from a Classical perspective or a Quantum perspective?

Apologies in advance for all the question marks! I'm generally interested in ways of visually conveying concepts- so would be curious to discover different approaches to the above.

Comment: You can see energy level diagrams for vaious nuclei in the big, bound version of the *Table of the Isotopes*. Individual nuclei can have confusing forests of available levels. Likewise the *Particle Data Book* has big diagrams for various groups of mesons and baryons and they are also pretty busy. So, while you might be *able* to construct such a beast, but I wonder how much use it would be.

Comment: This becomes *slightly* more feasible if you omit molecules, which have very complicated energy levels (they are almost not discrete in some cases) and have no limit to how large and complex they are.

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/51205/2451

Comment: Well, my thinking behind the above question, is that through laying out the big picture in front of me, I could better grasp the smaller details. Thanks for the recommendations- I shall check out those books. I am getting more of an idea of the size of data I would be dealing with now!

Comment: It will help to know that various fields use differnt conventions with regaurd to zero supressing the ground state mass in these diagrams. I'm sure you can figure it out from looking at the diagrams if you only recall that the ground state mass may or may not be represented.

Comment: Qmechanic- please feel free to merge this question with my previous one, if you feel it is too related.

Comment: @Seraphina: Your previous question is not a duplicate, but it provides some background context for your current question, which may be useful for potential answerers.

Comment: The standard way (in atomic physics) to compare energy levels in a diagram is a Grotian diagram. You might want to take a look at that first.

Answer (score 1):

Well, just for a start, you could compare the periodic table to the table of nuclides.  The table of nuclides is a little large for one page however.  Slightly different but also visually interesting is the chart of fundamental particles.  Google images is your friend

Comment: Excellent- shall go exploring those then.